# Как в wordpress получить id текущей страницы вне цикла?

Tags: wordpress

Люди подскажите пожалуйста как в wordpress получить id текущей страницы вне цикла?

Answer (score 3):

```
get_queried_object_id();
```

> Retrieve ID of the current queried object. Wrapper for `$wp_query->get_queried_object_id()`